# Comparing lists with dictviews

Tags: python, dictionary, set, dictview

[Dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) "are set-like objects" and can thus be used to compare dictionary contents with other objects.  Specifically,

- *key-views*: set-like
- *value-views*: not set-like
- *item-views*: set-like if (key, value) pairs are unique and hashable

The set-like nature of key-views allows bitwise comparisons.  In Python 3, we can find the intersection using the `&` operator.

```
hex_ids = {'#b0a7aa': '9976', '#595f5b': '19367', '#9a8f6a': '24095'}
hex_ids.keys()
# dict_keys(['#595f5b', '#9a8f6a', '#b0a7aa'])

{'#c7ccc0', '#9a8f6a', '#8a8e3e'} & hex_ids.keys()
# {'#9a8f6a'}
```

Oddly, comparing a `list` and key-view is also possible:

```
['#c7ccc0', '#9a8f6a', '#8a8e3e'] & hex_ids.keys()
# {'#9a8f6a'}
```

whereas `list` and `set` objects normally cannot be compared this way.

```
['#c7ccc0', '#9a8f6a', '#8a8e3e'] & set(['#595f5b', '#9a8f6a', '#b0a7aa'])
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'set'

['#c7ccc0', '#9a8f6a', '#8a8e3e'] & {['#595f5b', '#9a8f6a', '#b0a7aa']}
# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Aside from being set-like, **why can key-views be compared to lists using bitwise operators?**

---

Tested on: |Python 3.5.2|Python 3.4.4|Python 2.7.12 (using `viewkeys()`)|IPython 5.0.0|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the [`__rand__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rand__) method (short for "reflected and") on the `dict_keys` type.   Note that the reflected functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types, which is the case here.

```
>>> {}.keys().__rand__
<method-wrapper '__rand__' of dict_keys object at 0x109948f18>
```

For example:

```
>>> {0:0, 1:1}.keys().__rand__([1, 2])
{1}
```

For some reason this method was not implemented for sets, which is why that doesn't work:

```
>>> {0, 1}.__rand__([1, 2])
NotImplemented
```

I don't know the reason for this omission on sets, but I suspect it's probably "nobody has bothered to write it" because you can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) explicitly instead.